# Clean way to palce div boxes with border next to each other - resulting into a 1 px wide borders

Tags: css

[Ok following scenario in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rrL7A/). The squares are coming from a CMS, i cannot hard code something. I need a clean way to always get 1 border thickness. At the moment the border thickness is sometimes 1 px and sometimes 2 px. The width of the container is given and it will always be 3 squares wide. So it will never have, say, 2 squares. Always $number_of_squares % 3 === 0
See screenshot

[image]

Is there a trick to it?

HTML:

```
<div class="container"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
    display:inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: burlywood;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.container{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: white;
    border: none;
}
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rrL7A/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

give container `padding:1px 0 0 1px`;

& divs `margin:-1px 0 0 -1px`;

Here is jsFiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rrL7A/2/)

Comment: YES, cleanest possible solution